# Retrofit 2. Posting a list of objects that include a file

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to be able to send a list of objects that include an image per object.

```
{
  id: 0,
  file="/yy/xx.png",
  answers=[yellow, brown]
},
{
  id: 1,
  file="/zz/foo.png",
  answers=[not yellow, not brown]
}
```

How would I go about doing that? My idea right now is to do a  `List<PartMap>` and post that.

Answer (score 0):

Make an object with 3 atrbutes: int id, String file, String[] answers..then you set these objects, make a list and send then in the body os the @POST